# How to get the DISTICT (column) and then count them in Group In MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I have A huge table with lots of data and fields.
I need to get the distinct values from some column,and count them in to groups based on another column .

I tried something like below, But it count of distinct values in each group.
I don't want to count same value in different groups.

Any help appreciated!
Thanks In advance .

```
select distinct(A) as A, count(distinct(B)) as count_b, C from `some_table` group by A,C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select A, count(distinct B) as count_b, C 
from `some_table` group by A,C
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference in my problem, or output

Comment: @Sangeetha, could u please add some sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: I need Something like this
`
select distinct(A) as A, count(  select something from (select something from a table) where condition   )  as count_b, C from `some_table` group by A,C
`